# Linking to doxygen generated documentation externally

Tags: c++, enums, documentation, doxygen

When doxygen generates documentation for enum in the namespace, it adds sections of the form

```
<a name="a1234" doxytag="SomeNamespace::SomeEnumName"></a>
```

and the **a1234** can be use to access the documentation for **SomeNamespace::SomeEnumName** as follows

```
http://www.path_to_documentation/namespaceSomeNamespace.html#a1234
```

This is done by doxygen automatically, but if one need to link to the documentation of **SomeNamesace::SomeEnumName** from another external page.

Is there a way one can *know* the **a1234** name of the section? or can doxygen be configured to use a more *reasonable* name for the section which can then be predicted if one knows the entity being looked for? i.e. can doxygen be configured to generate names for sections to be something like

```
namespaceSomeNamespace.html#SomeNamespace__SomeEnumName
```

Comment: Is your external page also Doxygen? If yes, a [tagfile](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/external.html) is what you are looking for. If not, the generated tagfile (xml) may still help you to extract the information you are looking for in an automated way.